# React MUI DataGrid Add Custom Menu to Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui, material-react-table

As per the MUI custom component documentation https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/, I have created custom dropdown menu called Dashboard. Some reason it's doesn't align with the menu (see image below).

[image]

Here is the test code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-adn8vv?file=Demo.js

It also throwing an warning in console.
[image]

Comment: The example you are using as a basis also does not work now, apparently you should take it as a basis:
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/next/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/components/toolbar/GridToolbarDensitySelector.tsx